# no notifications being sent

Tags: members

My new member notifications are not being sent even though I have my email and notifications set to YES in the member prefs.

I CAN send emails through tools > communicate so I know email works.

I am using USER from solspace.  I also tried MX Notify Control but that doesn't work either.

My new members have no activations required but I still want to be notified.  What am I missing.

EE ver 2.5.5 
User 3.4.0

Comment: Are you using Solspace's User 'Email(s) for Admin Notification on Profile Update' in the User Module interface or ExpressionEngines built in Notification Preferences?

Answer (score 2):

so the notifications all came through, about 2 hours after they were submitted!!!

I was using the built in EE notifications of new members (not profile update)

Comment: I'm going to assume you are using SMTP mail option. Cause I think with PHP mail, if it can't communicate with the server, it doesn't try again, but I could be wrong. But yeah, sometimes mail doesn't go out immediately. I just setup Mandrill, http://mandrill.com, for a client and now plan to use it on all our set-ups. It tells you what's happening to CMS sent mail. So it would have told you of a potential soft bounce couldn't communicate with server. You replace SMTP server configuration with its SMTP info, and wall. It's beautiful, black hole of CMS email has a light turned on.